# Otsu's Thresholding Implementation not working properly

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have implemented otsu's threshold implementation which segments an image into foreground and background image.The output of my implementation seems off from the desired one. Any thoughts on it? Thanks in advance! Would really appreciate it someone can tell me how do i resolve the issue.

My output: 
For image 1-

[image]

For image 2-

[image]

My Code:

```
im1=imread('D:\root-image.pgm');
% im1=rgb2gray(im1);
[n,m]=size(im1);
 hst=imhist(im1);
mu=zeros(255,1);
N=0;
for i=1:255
    N=N+hst(i);
end
% The total mean level of the original image
for i=1:255
    mu(i)=mu(i)+((i.*hst(i))./N);
end


for T=1:254
    qb=0;
    muT=0;
    qo=0;
    for i=1:T
        qb=qb+(hst(i)./N); % probability of class occurence (background)
        m=m+((i.*hst(i))./N);% probability of class mean (background)
    end
    for i=T+1:255
        qo=qo+(hst(i)./N);% probability of class occurence (object)
    end
    sigma(T)=((mu(T)-(qb*muT))^2)/(qb*qo);
end
[Y,T] = max(sigma);

[n,m]=size(im1);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        if im1(i,j)>T
            im(i,j)=1;
        else
            im(i,j)=0;
        end
    end
end
figure(1);
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(im1);
% subplot(1,3,2);
% imhist(im1);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(im);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code, and I'll outline where it's wrong:

1. I'm simply nitpicking, but you can count the total number of pixels (`N`) by using [`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html)... it's just cleaner :)
2. In your original code, you are checking for the right threshold between 1 and 254.  You really should be checking from 0 to 255, as there are 256 possible intensities in your image.
3. You also need to change your `sigma` declaration so that there are 256 elements, not 255.  Remember, there are 256 possible intensities in your image.
4. Within your `for` loop for checking each intensity, when you are calculating the probability of class occurrences, you need to check for intensity 0 as well.  Because of the fact that MATLAB starts indexing arrays at 1, you'll need to offset your access index so that you're starting at 1.
5. Your definition of the variance between the object and background is slightly off.  You need to also calculate the probability of the class mean for the object as well.  You can check the code for more details.
6. Your probability of class mean definitions are slightly inaccurate.  You need to divide by `qb` and `qo`, not `N`.
7. You are using `m` to calculate then mean when you should be storing it in `muT`.
8. Finally, when you find the maximum of the variance between the object and background, you need to **subtract** by 1, as this will provide an intensity between 0 and 255.

As such, this is what your code looks like.  Note that I have omitted the code that thresholds your image.  I'm only providing the code that calculates the threshold for your image.

```
hst=imhist(im1);
sigma = zeros(256,1); %// Change
N = numel(im1); %// Change

for T=0:255 %// Change
    qb=0;
    muT=0;
    qo=0;
    muQ=0; %// Change
    for i=0:T %// Change
        qb=qb+(hst(i+1)./N); % probability of class occurence (background)
    end    
    for i=T+1:255 
        qo=qo+(hst(i+1)./N);% probability of class occurence (object)
    end
    for i=0:T%// Change        
        muT=muT+((i.*hst(i+1))./qb);% probability of class mean (background)    
    end
    for i=T+1:255 %// Change
        muQ=muQ+((i.*hst(i+1))./qo);% probability of class mean (object)        
    end   
    sigma(T+1) = qb*qo*((muT-muQ)^2); %// Change
end
[Y,T] = max(sigma);
T = T-1; %// Change - For 0 to 255
```

---

This code should now work.  I ran this code with my own implementation of Otsu, and I get the same calculated threshold.  To be honest, I find this code to be rather inefficient due to the many `for` loops.  What I would personally do is vectorize it, but I'll leave that to you as a learning exercise :)

---

## Edit

OK, I'll give in.  Here's some code that I wrote for Otsu that is more vectorized.  This essentially performs what you are doing above, but in a more vectorized manner.  You're more than welcome to use it for your own purposes, but do cite me if you intend to use it of course :)

```
%// Function that performs Otsu's adaptive bimodal thresholding
%// Written by Raymond Phan - Version 1.0
%// Input - im - Grayscale image
%// Output - out - Thresholded image via Otsu

function [out] = otsu(im)

%// Compute histogram
J = imhist(im);

%// Total number of intensities
L = length(J);

%// Some pre-processing stuff
%// Determine total number of pixels
num_pixels = sum(J(:));

%// Determine PDF
pdf = J / num_pixels;

%// Storing between-class variances for each intensity
s_b = zeros(1,L);

for idx = 1 : L
    %// Calculate w_0
    w_0 = sum(pdf(1:idx));

    %// Calculate w_1
    w_1 = 1 - w_0;

    %// Calculate u_0
    u_0 = sum((0:idx-1)'.*pdf(1:idx)) / w_0;

    %// Calculate u_1
    u_1 = sum((idx:L-1)'.*pdf(idx+1:L)) / w_1;

    % // Calculate \sigma_b^{2}
    s_b(idx) = w_0*w_1*((u_1 - u_0)^2);    
end

%// Find intensity that provided the biggest variance
[max_s_b T] = max(s_b);
T = T - 1; %// Must subtract by 1, since the index starts from 1

%// Now create an output image that thresholds the input image
out = im >= T;

end
```

---

## Edits by Divakar

Divakar (thanks!) has created vectorized code to replace the loop portion of the above function code and this essentially gets rid of the pre-allocation for `s_b`:

```
w_0 = cumsum(pdf);
w_1 = 1 - w_0;
u_0 = cumsum((0:L-1)'.*pdf)./w_0;
u_1 = flipud([0 ; cumsum((L-1:-1:1)'.*pdf((L:-1:2)))])./w_1;
s_b = w_0.*w_1.*((u_1 - u_0).^2);
```

Comment: @James Why would you want a recursive implementation?

Comment: i suppose it will run fast than the above code and my actual requirement is to write a recursive code of otsu.

Comment: Sure! It would be a really help

Comment: @James - Done!  Go ahead and take a look.  Note that a lot of the operations you're doing can be simplified with one or two lines of code.

Comment: I will cite you wherever i use it.

Comment: @James - Cool :)... now, I don't mind if you use it for homework.  Obviously, get rid of my name and all that... but for future use, please go ahead and give me credit where it's due.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng Would it be okay to edit your solution with a vectorized code? +1 BTW!

Comment: @Divakar - Sure! I'm curious.  Place it at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @Divakar - Thank you :).  BTW, I need some help in vectorizing some code.  I've found some code that performs a particular image processing task, but the code is rather inefficient.  I need to vectorize it, but the code is structured in such a way that I can't figure out how to vectorize it.  Do you mind if I enlist your help?

Comment: @rayryeng Sure hook me up! I can't gurantee to vectorize/speed it up, but could surely look into it for the possibilities.

Comment: @Divakar - Thank you :) This is quite involved: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9143086/blindgamma.m - Basically, the code performs blind gamma estimation.  Given an image, it estimates what the gamma an image has, and specifies what the inverse is to normalize the contrast of the image.  The original algorithm was meant for 1D signals, but for images, you would do this by breaking up your image into rows that are 1D signals, you apply the algorithm for each row, get the inverse gammas for all of them, then compute the average inverse gamma.

Comment: @Divakar - The code was originally meant for 1D signals.  I modified it slightly to get it to be 2D and with the behaviour that I specified and in order to get it working.  However, the original author has written it in such a way that I can't figure out the best way to vectorize it.  Any help you could give would be appreciated!  I didn't want to make this a StackOverflow post as I know it would be closed... and this is a huge undertaking.  I figured maybe if I asked someone nicely here (like you :)), I'd get a better answer.  Any help would certainly be appreciated, but don't go crazy!

Comment: @rayryeng Doesn't look like a lot of code, so it's good. So, let me get back to you on this? Not too urgent, is it? :)

Comment: @Divakar - Not at all :) Take your time.  It's something that I wouldn't mind using in a pipeline I'm designing, but it's very slow as there are so many `for` loops.  If you could, communicate with me via e-mail.  You can get the link on my profile page by looking at my info box. Is this ok? :)  BTW, thank you so so so much for helping.  I've spent a couple of days on it, and it's quite difficult.

Comment: @rayryeng I just noticed that hidden email address thing! Clever stuff! Yeah let me get back to you through that.

Comment: @Divakar - Thank you :) :).  BTW, you can make one yourself by using Google's Mail Hide service: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey - Once you're here, go to **My Account**, then click on **Protect Your Email**, then generate a new hide URL for your e-mail address.

Comment: @rayryeng Awesome, would try that, thank you on the pointers! :)