# Thresholding how to automatically find thresh

Tags: image-processing

is possible auto detect tresh value (for grayscale image)? 
I do not want to enter a value , but I want found automatically.
How can I do this?

Comment: what language? One very common method is **otsu's method** it is avaliable in matlab and opencv

Comment: possible duplicate of [Otsu's Thresholding Implementation not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829725/otsus-thresholding-implementation-not-working-properly)